# How do I create logic that mirrors the visual state of the game without tying the logic to the animation?

Tags: animation

I'm implementing a type of action that depends on the completion of an animation; specifically, a character throwing a grenade should, at the end of the animation, spawn a grenade.  This seems to imply that I should be creating code that reacts to the completion of the animation, code that depends on the framerate: when the last frame is displayed, or immediately after, the processes that spawn a grenade should run.

I've been reading around and it seems that the consensus is that tying physics to the animation is bad practice.  I can code some workarounds that decouples the animation from the logic.  I am thinking that I can add an observer to the mix that pings all interested pieces of code that "the animation finished", or the like, so the animation doesn't know anything about the logic, and vice versa.

I can code workarounds, but they're that, workarounds.  They're code that's trying to detach logic from the event that triggers it, but they're inherently bound together; a grenade *should* spawn after a character throws it.  If animation and logic are to run separately, how *should* I implement a grenade spawning system that doesn't take the character animation frames into account?

Comment: Most Game Engine that I know of (Unity3D, Cocos2d) use FrameEvent to some extend, doesn't that solve your problem?

Comment: You should specify the language you use.